# How to prevent Magento 2.3.7 product image processing to mess with file size

Tags: magento, magento-2.3

I've uploaded some product images both with csv import and backend interface of magento 2.3 and I noticed that the file size on the frontend is 3x the size of the file I uploaded.

For example, I uploaded a 1200x1200px image (with custom Huffman lossless compression) around 600Ko. After Magento process the image the file is 2.2Mo on the frontend!

I've disable Frontend Image Resize on the backend and tried both GD2 and ImageMagick processor but it doesn't change anything !

Is there a way to disable image processing and just tell Magento to link Images uploaded on var/import/product_images to the actual products without doing anything on the files ?